# Spacy | is it possible to remove the hardcoded limit on lengths in the phrasematcher?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, match-phrase

I'm using Spacy library on python3.6, I have an array of 700 terms and a PharseMatcher that work with it.

It worked great when I had 10-12 terms but when I use a lot of terms it throws the error:

```
ValueError: [T001] Max length currently 10 for phrase matching
```

When I looked for it online all I found is this issue on the project in
[Github](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1711)

But it seems like it closed without changes were made in the project, Before I try to write the classification by myself without the use of the Spacy PhraseMatcher, Does anyone knows how to go over this error and use a huge list of terms when building a PharseMatcher, or maybe can recommand a better way to do such a thing (classification of text to subjects) by Spacy or any other python nlp / non-nlp library?

Thanks!